# Webpack Splitting React Components into "0.js" "1.js" etc. etc

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am unable to re-create the splitting of React components into separate files e.g. `0.js`, `1.js`, `2.js` etc. for code-splitting and reducing the bundle.js file. Does anyone happen to know how this outcome would be produced? I tried recreating it with `ChunkManifest` and `webpack-manifest` plugins but it just wouldn't do it. Any advice would be awesome!

**routes.js**

```
function errorLoading(err) {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
}

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
      {
        path: 'signup',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./modules/App/components/Authentication/Login.js')
            .then(loadRoute(cb))
            .catch(errorLoading);
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'verify',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./modules/App/components/Authentication/Verify.js')
            .then(loadRoute(cb))
            .catch(errorLoading);
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'password-reset',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./modules/App/components/Authentication/PasswordReset.js')
            .then(loadRoute(cb))
            .catch(errorLoading);
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'new-password',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./modules/App/components/Authentication/NewPassword.js')
            .then(loadRoute(cb))
            .catch(errorLoading);
        }
      }
    ]
  }  
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kind of code splitting is accomplished in a few ways:

- `require.ensure()`
- `System.import` (This will be deprecated in webpack v3)
- `import()`

Here is a link from our new docs page which specifies some examples of code splitting with react. https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-load-react/

(You can see here it is also referred to as lazy-loading modules)

Comment: awesome! I'll look into this link `https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/huge-apps` and get back to you :)

Comment: I followed the link `https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/ex‌​amples/huge-apps` and it worked! :)

Comment: Previous link are broken, just google "huge app reactjs", I found this: (it contains a copy of original link) https://github.com/echenley/react-router-huge-apps-refactor